# Kafka Connect HDFS - How to make it work?

Tags: hdfs, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

This is not a very specific question. However, I have not found a single document in which it is explained how do you actually use kafka - hdfs connector.

Basically, I have a kafka topic containing json encoded strings. I would like to send the data to HDFS as avro formatted data.

Any help would be more than welcome!

Comment: http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/index.html

Comment: Found that document, it does not explain anything. thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

What specifically are you trying to achieve with the HDFS-Connector. While docs certainly could use some help they do cover the basics for how to both configure and run the hdfs-connector. If you could be a little more specific as to the goal you are trying to achieve it will be easier for us to offer you some guidance.

Thanks, 
Ryan

Comment: Ryan, thanks for your reply.

Basically, I have a kafka topic containing json encoded strings. I would like to send the data to HDFS as avro formatted data.